# Floating footer hits absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a footer that is responsive and sticks to the bottom right of a page but can't get it to work consistently when a absolutely positioned div is on the same page.

The code I am using can be seen at:

```
http://192.241.203.146/sample-page/
```

I have tried:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 40px;
```

As well as:

```
float: right;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
margin-bottom: 40px;
margin-top: 40px;
```

To get it to work, but it does not respect the absolutely positioned content on the page when it is resized down to mobile. It clashes like so:

[image]

I know that using position:absolute means that the div is removed from the flow of objects but I need to use it on the element in the middle of the page to avoid the objects jumping around when I use jQuery fades.

I suspect this is because it is not inside a span or row as per the bootstrap base I am using. Is that the problem?

I'm at a loss here - any guidance appreciated :)

Comment: Why don't you take out the `position: absolute` from `.abouttext`? It seems to work for me.

Comment: But that breaks the fadein effect I'm using :(

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the div is normal to the page, but his position is absolute. Inspecting your code i saw this:

[image]

if you want the footer is always visible in the bottom, you can wrap the footer to the div which width will be 100% of the width of the page. Like this:

```
div#footer_container{
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100px;
position: relative;
}
div#footer_container div#footer{
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
}
```

Result: 
[image: Result]

Red - main container of your page, Green - container of your footer (its always will be after the main container), Blue - your footer.

P.S. sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found it!

Try this:

```
.main {
   padding-bottom: 140px;
}
```

It works for me even if I reduce the width of the browser.